# Conditional filtering and nested loops in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<Request xmlns:ns0="http://Request">
  <Lines>
    <Line>
      <requestid>76</requestid>
      <Code>C001</Code>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <requestid>77</requestid>
      <Code>C002</Code>
    </Line>
  </Lines>      
  <Conflict>
    <responseid>76</responseid>
    <responsecode>WB</responsecode>
    <cService>
      <responseid>73</responseid>
      <responsecode>HA</responsecode>
    </cService>
    <cService>
      <responseid>7600</responseid>
      <serviceCode>PP</serviceCode>
    </cService>
  </Conflict>      
  <Conflict>
    <responseid>77</responseid>
    <responsecode>WB7</responsecode>
    <cService>
      <responseid>745</responseid>
      <responsecode>HAQ</responsecode>
    </cService>
    <cService>
      <responseid>7234</responseid>
      <serviceCode>PP</serviceCode>
    </cService>
  </Conflict>      
  <Conflict>
    <responseid>77</responseid>
    <responsecode>WBC</responsecode>
    <cService>
      <responseid>72341</responseid>
      <responsecode>HAC</responsecode>
    </cService>
    <cService>
      <responseid>98</responseid>
      <responsecode>PPC</responsecode>
    </cService>
  </Conflict>
</Request>
```

and required output should be as shown below.

```
    <Output xmlns:ns0="http://Response">
      <Lines>
        <Line>
          <responseid>76</responseid>
          <code>WB</code>
          <Features>
            <ExistingFeature>
              <responseid>76</responseid>                           
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>76</responseid>                             
              </CFeature>
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>76</responseid>                                
              </CFeature>
            </ExistingFeature>
          </Features>
        </Line>
        <Line>
          <Num>77</Num>
          <Features>
            <ExistingFeature>
              <responseid>77</responseid>
              <code>WB7</code>
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>77</responseid>                
              </CFeature>
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>77</responseid>                
              </CFeature> 
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>77</responseid>                
              </CFeature> 
          <CFeature>
                <responseid>77</responseid>                
              </CFeature>             
            </ExistingFeature>
          </Features>
        </Line>        
      </Lines>
</Output>
```

So could you please help me to achieve this in XSLT.
Because i am trying in multiple ways but not able because i am poor in xslt.

Scenario.
Actually there should be one line created for each line in the input and also there are one or more conlicts are there for each and every line in the input based on requestID(i.e 76 or 77).
So i have to group the conflicts based on these ID in a single  node in the output for each occurance of lines in the input with all the corresponding matched conflicts in the input.

So could you please help me to write xslt for this scenario.

Comment: This is possible to do, but you provide a very scant description of the requirements. For example, Why the first result (`Line`) has completely different structure (`responsed` and `code) that the second `Lne` hasn't??????????

Comment: what you have tried in xslt

Comment: Yes. RequestID in the line and ResponseID in the Conflict Node are same. So we have to compare both the Request and RepsonseID.So there may be one or more Cservice nodes will exist in the Conflict node. But we don't need to consider the ResponseID in the CService node. I mean what ever the ResponseID in the CService node we should have to populate it uder the correponding Line node in the output based on RequestID in the Line(Request) and ResponseID(In the Request).

Comment: What i mean to say is all these nodes are repeatables only. But we have to create one LINE node in the output for each and every LINE node in the input with all the corresponding conflicts in the request itself based on the request and reposne IDs in the Input message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="incomekey" match="/Request/Conflict" use="responseid" /> 
  <xsl:template match="/Lines" >
    <Lines>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Line" />
    </Lines>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Line" >
    <Line>
      <xsl:variable name="tmp" select="requestid" />
      <xsl:for-each select="key('incomekey', $tmp)" >
        <xsl:variable name="strCount" select="position()" />
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 2">
          <responseid>
            <xsl:value-of select="requestid/text()" />
          </responseid>
          <code>
            <xsl:value-of select="Code/text()" />
          </code>
        </xsl:if>
        <Features>
          <ExistingFeature>
            <responseid>
              <xsl:value-of select="responseid" />
            </responseid>
            <code>
              <xsl:value-of select="responsecode" />
            </code>
            <xsl:for-each select="cService">
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>
                  <xsl:value-of select="responseid"/>
                </responseid>                              
              </CFeature>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </ExistingFeature>
        </Features>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Line>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using the above script. But its genrating the output for Second Line(77) as shown below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Line>
        <responseid>77</responseid>
        <code>WB</code>
        <Features>
          <ExistingFeature>
            <responseid>77</responseid>
            <code>WB7</code>
            <CFeature>
              <responseid>745</responseid>
            </CFeature>
            <CFeature>
              <responseid>7234</responseid>
            </CFeature>
          </ExistingFeature>
        </Features>
          <Features>
            <ExistingFeature>
              <responseid>77</responseid>
              <code>WBC</code>
              <CFeature>
                 <responseid>72341</responseid>
              </CFeature>
              <CFeature>
                <responseid>98</responseid>
              </CFeature>
             </ExistingFeature>
        </Features>
      </Line>
```

If you observe this node its creating two seperate Features node for each Conflict node in the Request with 77(RequestID).
So insetead of that i need it to be populate like shown below in the second Line node in the output.

```
<Features>
    <ExistingFeature>
      <responseid>77</responseid>
      <code>WB7</code>
      <CFeature>
        <responseid>745</responseid>
      </CFeature>
      <CFeature>
        <responseid>7234</responseid>
      </CFeature>
      <CFeature>
        <responseid>72341</responseid>
      </CFeature>
      <CFeature>
        <responseid>98</responseid>
      </CFeature>
    </ExistingFeature>
  </Features>
```